# Symbolic link set but not changes until reboot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symlink

I wrote a deployment script and in final step I have following code:

```
ln -sf /link/to/latest/release symlink/to/current;
```

I try to set the symbolic link or update if it exist, theoretically it works and with `ls -l` I see that correct directory was linked.

But to see the changes in browser I have to reboot the server, is there maybe something wrong with permissions or the way I set the symlink?

Comment: I doubt that permissions is the issue. What kind of web application files do you have in `/link/to/latest/release` ? php ? ruby ? python ? java ?... Does this application require to be started as a service (this will greatly depend on its type) ? Does this application maintains any kind of cache while it is running ? Why do you reboot your entire server and not just reload/restart your webserver or restart your application or clear its cache ? You may also have to stop your application before you update the symlink and restart it after. This is a wide question as is.

Comment: It's PHP application and it has cache, but I think the good point is to restart php-fpm, in the last step I remove also cache.